# Setting the database in InfluxDb using PHP API

Tags: php, influxdb

I am trying to connect influxDB with PHP and i can say i was almost successful all thanks to Corley for developing PHP api. I am finding difficult to set the database on which my query has to be applied.

Below is the sample PHP code I am working on, How to choose the specific database from the available list of databases.?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My first PHP page</h1>

<?php
use DateTime;
use DateTimeZone;
use InfluxDB\Options;
use InfluxDB\Client;
use InfluxDB\Adapter\GuzzleAdapter;
use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleHttpClient;
use InfluxDB\Integration\Framework\TestCase as InfluxDBTestCase;
require 'composertest/vendor/autoload.php';
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
$http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$options = new Options();
$options->setUsername("xyz");
$options->setPassword("1234");

$adapter = new GuzzleAdapter($http, $options);
$client = new Client($adapter);


//I need to select database "Test"

var_dump($client->query('select * from "app-search"'));
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you asked this question in SO, on influxdb@googlegroups.com, and  via email to support@influxdb.com. The answer to the support@ ticket was (with thanks to Ross McDonald):

> I believe what you are looking for is the `selectDB()` function. Here
>   is a small sample that can be inserted towards the bottom of your
>   example code:
>
> ```
> $database = $client->selectDB('Test');
> var_dump($database->query('select * from "app-search"'));
> ```
>
> Where queries are run using the `$database` variable, as opposed to
>   the `$client` variable.
>
> The InfluxDB PHP driver is actually developed and maintained by the
>   InfluxDB community (and not by the InfluxDB organization itself), so
>   more information about the driver (including code examples) can be
>   found on the Github page here:
>
> https://github.com/influxdb/influxdb-php